# Angular firebase ERROR, no firebaseApp has been created even though i created

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angularfire

I have this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmX15.jpg)

I have initialized app but error saying it doesnt.

Here is my angular `app.module.ts`:

```
import { getFirestore, provideFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { getStorage, provideStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { getAuth, provideAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { provideFirebaseApp, initializeApp } from '@angular/fire/app';

import { environment } from './environments/environment';

@NgModule({
....
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig)),
    provideAuth(() => getAuth()),
    provideFirestore(() => getFirestore()),
    provideStorage(() => getStorage()),
  ],
})
```

What is the problem?

Tried to import AngularFireModule but still got a lot of errors

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Please edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Think I'm seeing same thing on first click to load a component that injects Storage. Second click to open and it works fine. Seems like initializeApp is not loading when the app initializes. The error looks like this `ERROR FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call initializeApp() first (app/no-app)`

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the `AngularFireModule` before you try to initialize your providers

`AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig)`